# map city/zipcode polygons using google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, polygon

I am looking for a javascript library that supports the ability to pass a zipcode or city as a parameter, and get a list of x,y coordinates to draw a polygon using google maps?

Does this exist? Does the google maps API support such queries? I am looking for an array of coordinates similar to those that google uses to draw maps on a google query:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps API doesn't support that kind of solution. There are a couple other places from which you can get the coordinates, though:

**Flickr API**

There is a Flickr API based on photos that people tag, but it's only as accurate as the people who tag photos: so it's good enough for bootstrapping but probably not for production: http://karya-blog.blogspot.com/2012/12/fetching-city-polygons-with-flickr-api.html

**Natural Earth Data**

An accurate alternative is www.naturalearthdata.com.  To get that data from there you just need to make two requests: one with the city name and one with their ID to get the parameters:

unlock.edina.ac.uk/ws/search?name=berlin&gazetteer=naturalearth&format=json

and then

unlock.edina.ac.uk/ws/footprintLookup?format=json&identifier=14126951

and you're set :)

**Mapzen**

If it's possible for you to pre-fetch the data, go for Mapzen, they have a full and pretty accurate database: https://mapzen.com/data/borders/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I do not think there is any magical getZipCodeBoundaries method in the Google Maps API. However, what you want to do can and has been done. [Please see the implementation](http://maps.huge.info/zip.htm), and this [thread on Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-How-Do-I/browse_thread/thread/8f765061934d4e22?pli=1) concerning the process. Is the first link similar to what you're hoping to accomplish? Also, there is a [neighborhood API offered from Zillow under the CC license](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm). You might want to look into that and see if it breaks neighborhoods down by zipcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can get polygon coordenates in json for using with googlemaps using openstreetmap.
Go to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/
search a place like "Partido de Ituzaingó"

Steps:

- Click on "details"
- Look for the OSM ID and copy it (control+c), example: `2018776`
- Go to http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py
- Paste the ID in
- Download the polygon

Answer (score -1):

Look on this site [Twitter geo api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/id/%3aplace_id) You have few modes of search, and it gives You boundary box for cities. I am using it now on My site. Try f.e. this [link](https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/535f0c2de0121451.json) and U will see the results.