# Getting zip code using HTTP request

Tags: linux, geolocation

I have a Linux based device and need to find the zip code of the area where the device is installed. I was wondering if it is possible to get the zip code using a HTTP request or getting latitude and longitude without entering address?

I have seen other similar questions on Stack Overflow and it seems to me that we need to enter the longitude and latitude and then use the Haversine formula to calculate the zip code.

Is there any way to get the zip code or latitude and longitude by using the Internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[ZIP codes are not geographical areas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112899/how-to-get-the-bounding-coordinates-for-a-us-postalzip-code/13114578#13114578)** so your best bet is to associate it with an address...

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you are looking for?  How can you possible get lat/lon for a location without entering an address or using a location aware service?  If approximate area is good enough, you can get the geolocation of the IP address using maxmind: http://www.maxmind.com/en/javascript_demo