# How to request polygons from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am interested in an analogue of http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
I.e. to be able to make request and get some kind of polygon coordinates:

"geojson":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.464761,44.600998],[-87.459755,44.599569],[-87.459745,44.601012],[-87.463143,44.601],[-87.464761,44.600998]]]}

Nominatim is good, but it lacks of some data (I am interested in data about cities and counties of Canada). For example, Google Map knows about the Ontario districts and highlights them, but OpenStreetMap - does not. As well as for some cities - where OpenStreetMap shows a dot, Google Maps shows full polygon.

Can it be done with Google Maps?

Other alternatives will work as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [map city/zipcode polygons using google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525132/map-city-zipcode-polygons-using-google-maps)

Comment: It has two answers - one which points to the Twitter API, and one which is irrelevant. The Twitter one would work, but it is not convenient given API time limitations, so I would like still to know about alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done via GMaps API: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43292/how-to-geocode-an-address-to-a-polygon

But be also aware of the legal restriction of the API and the commercial dataset, esp. if you want to use it regularly or for bulk processing: http://www.google.com/help/legalnotices_maps.html

I would also consider to help OSM to improve the dataset. This can be done by contacting the local community and offering help to ask for official public datasources. Esp. in the case of political boundaries, there is no way to get this material on the ground: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Canada

Comment: Sadly, Gmaps API just gives a rectangle boundary, not a shaped polygon.